# Why is my cursor recording 1 extra count?

Tags: sql-server, cursor

I created a function with a cursor to count all the entrees in my other table.
When I do `PRINT dbo.cursorEnroll ();`
I get 11 as an output when I only had 10 entrees in my table.
@@FETCH = 0 should mean fetch is successful, and thus should only SET studentsEnrolled 10 times. I am confused where this extra count comes from.

DISCLAIMER: I know this isn't the best way to count the number of entries in a table. However, I am just learning and practicing the use of cursors.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.cursorEnroll ()
    RETURNS INT AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @studentsEnrolled INT
        SET @studentsEnrolled = 0
        DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR
            SELECT enrollementID
                FROM courseEnrollment
        OPEN myCursor;

        FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @studentsEnrolled

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @studentsEnrolled = @studentsEnrolled+1
                    FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @studentsEnrolled
            END;
        CLOSE myCursor
        RETURN @studentsEnrolled

    END;
```

Comment: What? why do you need a stinking cursor? `select @studentsEnrolled = count(*) from courseEnrollment`  that will me many times faster

Comment: order of operations... you update the count THEN fetch a row. That means you fetch 10 rows of data, and then one failed fetch because you hit the end of the result set, but you've already incremented the count

Comment: Where exactly do I put my SET statement? If I put my SET statement after the FETCH, I get a printed answer of 12 o_O.

Comment: This is an example of something that should not under any circumstances be done using a cursor. Cursors are extremely poor techniques to use and are the techniwue of last resort not the first choice. You need to learn to think in sets. @SQLMenace has told you the better way to do this.

Comment: @HLGEM Yeah I know this isn't a legitimate use for a cursor. I am just learning and practicing how to use them.

Comment: @krikara, unless you are a dba, it is unlikely you will ever need them. Learn the more useful things first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you fetch `enrollementID` into `@studentsEnrolled` and then add 1. For last row `enrollementID = 10` then you get 11 as result.

Comment: Yes, you mix `@studentsEnrolled` counter for counting purposes and also to store cursor row value.

Comment: Ok, so the Set statement is just not needed at all. /facepalm

Comment: Actually you do need the Set statement if you want to capture the count of the rows, you don't need the set statement if you just want to capture the Id from the last row returned. There is no guarantee that the id's are returned in order (you haven't sorted the SQL statement) and there is no guarantee that they correlate to row count (could be gaps in id range like: 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 12). If you want the greatest value, remove the SET and add an ORDER BY to the query, if you want count then keep the SET and use separate variables for SET and FETCH